# ListPicker SelectedItem raises InvalidOperationException exception

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have XAML code like this:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="lstStatus" SelectionMode="Single" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListPickerItemTemplate}" FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListPickerFullModeItemTemplate}" FullModeHeader="Items" CacheMode="BitmapCache"/>

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="ListPickerItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10 0 0 0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="ListPickerFullModeItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10 0 0 0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

I populate the item source using:

```
public List<Items> PopulatelstStatus()
{
    List<Items> source = new List<Items>();
    source.Add(new Items() { Name = "Booked" });
    source.Add(new Items() { Name = "Confirmed" });
    source.Add(new Items() { Name = "Completed" });
    source.Add(new Items() { Name = "Cancelled" });
    return source;
}

lstStatus.ItemsSource = PopulatelstStatus();
```

The problem is that when I want to set SelectedItem property of this ListPicker it raises an InvalidOperationException. I have tried the following.

```
var item = PopulatelstStatus().SingleOrDefault(n => n.Name == equipBooking.Status.Description);

lstStatus.SelectedItem = item;
```

and

```
var item = PopulatelstStatus().SingleOrDefault(n => n.Name == equipBooking.Status.Description);

lstStatus.SelectedIndex = PopulatelstStatus().IndexOf(item);
```

Comment: Find out the position of the element you want to change in the list and then use lstStatus.SelectedIndex = 2 (or any number within the range) .

Comment: Yeah , that's what i tried also ! let me post my code for that

Comment: Assign .IndexOf(item) 's value to a variable and check if its working fine .. or you may even try some number directly

Comment: One other possible cause is InvalidCrossThreadAccess .. Try placing your `lstStatus.SelectedIndex = 1;` in `Dispatcher.BefinInvoke(()=>{ lstStatus.SelectedIndex = 1; });` and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the SelectedItem, you need to set it with an item that is contained with the ItemsSource. Each time you call the `PopulatelstStatus` method, it generates a new collection of items. This new collection of items are different than the collection you set as the ItemsSource of ListPicker.

It looks like you like is static. You should cache the list and use it.

```
private List<Items> _source;
public List<Items> PopulatelstStatus()
{
    if(_source == null)
    {
        _source = new List<Items>();
        _source.Add(new Items() { Name = "Booked" });
        _source.Add(new Items() { Name = "Confirmed" });
        _source.Add(new Items() { Name = "Completed" });
        _source.Add(new Items() { Name = "Cancelled" });
    }
    return _source;
}
```

Now when you call the `PopulatelstStatus` it will always be the same collection and when you get an item from it, it will be the same item contained in your ListPicker.